# SSRS access to URL

Tags: windows, reporting-services, uac, ssrs-2014

I've installed `SQL Server 2014`, and now when I go `Report Manager URL` I receive error:

> User 'Domain\name' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

I've red several articles which describes how to solve that. But, firstly, I have minimal knowledge of Windows administration, and, secondly, Windows 10 Home Edition really sucks, everything there differes much compared to Win7. I've tried to run `Edge` as Administrator, but it doesn't have such a function. I've tried to fix that by `secpol.msc`, but it doesn't exist in home edition.

Please, help me to run URL by local user.

**EDIT**
I thought that Edge replacesInternet Explorer, but it didn't. I ran Explorer as Administrator, it worked. There I have added my local user as admin, but neverthless, I can't open URL with my local user, exception is the same as above. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don't know why Microsoft does this. It's kinda like it's broken right out of the box, huh?

Anyway, I just ran into this issue myself recently, so it's fresh in my mind, and you're on the right track! But it's important to realize that there are two different places where you need to add yourself as a user.

1) After running IE as administrator, click 'Site Settings' in the top right, navigate to the 'Security' menu on the left, and add the 'System Administrator' role assignment to your user name.

2) Click 'Home' in the upper left, and then click 'Folder Settings' in the middle of the blue menu bar. I would suggest adding all the available role assignments to your user name.

That should get you back in action ;-)

**EDIT**: Oh yes, and [add the Report Manager URL to 'Trusted Sites' in your internet settings](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b5a8763-84ce-46d0-b011-067ad39223d1/does-not-have-required-permissions?forum=sqlexpress).